# Can i give sed an array for its path?

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I'm new to the world of macOS and Unix, but I have to work with it.
My question is: Am I able to give the sed-command an array, which contains paths, so that sed uses the contained variable as a path?
I try to manipulate the dock of a User, that I have identified before that.
My code to this point is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

...
...

for change in '${plistToModify[@]}'
do
  sed 's<_CFURLSTRING>file:///Applications/name_old.app</_CFURLSTRING>#<_CFURLSTRING>file:///Applications/name_new.app</_CFURLSTRING>#' '${plistToModify[$change]}'
done

killall Dock
```

(I switched the name of the app, fyi)

I tried double-quoting the array at the beginning of the for-loop and at the end of sed, but nothing worked

The array contains a unknown number of paths, which look like this:

```
/Users/theUser/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist
```

Is this possible in the first place or am I missing something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this an associative or an indexed array?  If indexed then you need `"$change"`, not `${plistToModify[$change]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `sed` can handle multiple files, whether they come from an array or not does not matter.

#### Your Specific Case

In your specific example you can write

```
sed 'yourSedCommand' "${plistToModify[@]}"
```

#### General Case

`sed 'cmd' file1 file2 file3` is the same as `a=(file1 file2 file3); sed 'cmd' "${a[@]}"`. Bash expands `"${a[@]}"` before `sed` even runs. There is no way for `sed` to tell the difference.

`sed` itself will handle multiple files as if it was one big file, therefore `sed 'cmd' file1 file2 file3` is the same as `cat file1 file2 file3 | sed 'cmd'`.

Only if you use the `-i` flag to edit files inplace `sed -i` will treat multiple files individually.

Comment: Thank you, that made the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong type of quotes. Parameter expansion does not occur within single quotes. You have to write `"${plistToModify[$change]}"`.

Comment: I tried that, made no difference. Im still getting the same error: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/Users/theUser/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist")

Comment: Just be careful to escape (prefix with \) any `$` characters in the pattern.